# Pyinstaller Keyring Windows 32 bit

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, 32-bit, python-keyring

I have the following python test code:

```
import keyring
print(keyring.get_keyring())
keyring.set_password("a","b","c")
print(keyring.get_password("a","b"))
```

If I run this code using a 32 bit python or a 64 bit one I obtain the following output (as expected):

```
<keyring.backends.Windows.WinVaultKeyring object at 0x00000187B7DD6358>
c
```

My purpose is to build two standalone executable (32bit and 64bit): in order to achieve that I'm using pyinstaller and the following command (test.py is the name of the file containing the python code shown above)

```
pyinstaller --onefile test.py
```

If I run the 64 bit exe I obtain the following output (as expected):

```
<keyring.backends.Windows.WinVaultKeyring object at 0x00000187B7DD6358>
c
```

Instead, if I run the 32 bit exe I obtain the following output:

```
<keyring.backends.fail.Keyring object at 0x05463ED0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    keyring.set_password("a","b","c")
  File "site-packages\keyring\core.py", line 47, in set_password
  File "site-packages\keyring\backends\fail.py", line 23, in get_password
RuntimeError: No recommended backend was available. Install the keyrings.alt package if you want to use the non-recommended backends. See README.rst for details.
[2732] Failed to execute script test
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Thanks,

Daniele

Comment: How do you obtain your 32 bit executable? If you want your final exe to be executable on both 32 and 64 bits, you should install `pyinstaller` with your 32 bits version of python and produce the exe from there.

Comment: I'm using a 32 bits python to produce the executable: anyway I just solved the issue using an alternate keyring (see the answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using an alternate keyring backend. If I change my code from:

```
import keyring
print(keyring.get_keyring())
keyring.set_password("a","b","c")
print(keyring.get_password("a","b"))
```

to:

```
import keyring
from keyrings.alt import Windows
keyring.set_keyring(Windows.RegistryKeyring())
print(keyring.get_keyring())
keyring.set_password("a","b","c")
print(keyring.get_password("a","b"))
```

it works.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up the keyrings.alt file from the Keyring Github page does seem to work, and would explain why this was only an issue in Keyring>12, since it was included in the Module before that. I was also able to work around it by installing `pip install pywin32` and running the following additions:

```
import keyring
import win32timezone
from keyring.backends import Windows
keyring.set_keyring(Windows.WinVaultKeyring())
print(keyring.get_keyring())
keyring.set_password("a","b","c")
print(keyring.get_password("a","b"))
```